# Merge fews div in block of individual divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I an creating a number board in which certain numbers needed to merge as single cell. Please refer how the output look like the picture [image]

Flowing is the HTML part of it, I used margin for non-merge cells and border for merge cells , but the alignment of the cells distorted. How can I achieve in different way? Any leads or runnable links will be helpfull

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">14</div>
    <div class="child">15</div>
    <div class="child">16</div>
    <div class="child">17</div>
    <div class="child merged">18</div>
    <div class="child merged">19</div>
    <div class="child merged">20</div>
    <div class="child">34</div>
    <div class="child">35</div>
    <div class="child">36</div>
    <div class="child">37</div>
    <div class="child">38</div>
    <div class="child">39</div>
    <div class="child">40</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have tried
[image]

```
.parent {
    display: flex;        
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
 }
 .child {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
 }
 .merged{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-color: #1792E5;
    background-color: #1792E5;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the merged cells and whats the desired outcome is?

Comment: its looks good, can you explain again please what isnt works for you with the output?

Comment: @TheDaniel: The desired out come you can see in the picture

Comment: Ok then, can you describe how it looks like right now? What do you mean by distorted. Please add your css and any other code that is relevant.

Comment: Do you have css for parent and css?

Comment: show us how it looks like right now. So we can see the issue or describe it at least

Comment: Updated with what I have tried,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
var y = 'child merged';
var c, d, e;
for (var i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++) {

    c = x[i - 1].getAttribute('class');
    d = x[i + 1].getAttribute('class');
    e = x[i].getAttribute('class');

    if (c === y && e === y && d === y) {
        x[i].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;');
    }
    else if (c !== y && e === y && d !== y) {
        x[i].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;');
    }
    else if (c !== y && e === y && d === y) {
        x[i].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;');
    }
    else if (c === y && e === y && d !== y) {
        x[i].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;');
    }
    else if (c === y && x[i - 2] === undefined && e !== y) {
        x[i - 1].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;');
    }
    else if (i === x.length - 2 && d === y) {
        x[i + 1].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;');
    } else { }

    if (x[i + 2] === undefined && e === y && d === y) {
        x[i + 1].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;');
    }

    if (c === y && x[i - 2] === undefined && e === y) {
        x[i - 1].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;');
    }

    if (i === 7 || i === 14 || i === 21) {
        x[i - 1].style.marginRight = '5px';
        x[i].style.marginLeft = '5px';
    }

}
```

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.merged {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background: #1792E5;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child merged">14</div>
    <div class="child merged">15</div>
    <div class="child">16</div>
    <div class="child">17</div>
    <div class="child merged">18</div>
    <div class="child merged">19</div>
    <div class="child merged">20</div>
    <div class="child merged">34</div>
    <div class="child">35</div>
    <div class="child">36</div>
    <div class="child merged">37</div>
    <div class="child merged">38</div>
    <div class="child">39</div>
    <div class="child merged">40</div>
    <div class="child merged">41</div>
    <div class="child merged">42</div>
    <div class="child">43</div>
    <div class="child merged">44</div>
    <div class="child">45</div>
    <div class="child ">46</div>
    <div class="child merged">47</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the issue not solved, the space between blue and white boxes are miss aligned

Comment: @Lejin KR, Yes you are right! Can I use JavaScript?

Comment: It will fail if one more bock of merged cells come, for example if i want to merge 35,36 thanks for helping out

Comment: I think all the bugs in the code have already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in the css file that fixed the issue. Let me know if you have any questions

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.middle {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background: blue;
  border:10px;
}

.end {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: 10px;
    background: blue;
}

.start {
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    border: 10px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">14</div>
    <div class="child">15</div>
    <div class="child">16</div>
    <div class="child">17</div>
    <div class="child merged start">18</div>
    <div class="child merged middle">19</div>
    <div class="child merged end">20</div>
    <div class="child">34</div>
    <div class="child">35</div>
    <div class="child">36</div>
    <div class="child">37</div>
    <div class="child">38</div>
    <div class="child">39</div>
    <div class="child">40</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```